# Scrollbar moving to right instead of left

Tags: c#, charts, scrollbar

I have made a chart which dynamically draw a spike when data received. 
In this chart I have made a scrollbar, so only 20 datapoints get shown at on time.

```
public void Chart()
{
    ChartArea mov = SleepMovChar.ChartAreas["Movement"];
    mov.AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 12;
    mov.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
    mov.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.All ^ ScrollBarButtonStyles.ResetZoom;
    mov.AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
    mov.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
    mov.AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 20;
}
```

My problem is, that I want that scrollbar to move to right when data received. At the time now, it moves to left, so the first data is shown. I just want that the latest data is shown instead, so that the scrollbar follows the data receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the visible area to follow the new data like in an oscilloscope, you can set the scroll position :

```
Series S1 = SleepMovChar.Series["yourSeriesByNameOrNumber"];
mov.AxisX.ScaleView.Position = S1.Points.Count - mov.AxisX.ScaleView.Size;
```

You will need to repeat this whenever you have added data points..