# How do I make a dynamic chart?

Tags: c#, charts

I am getting a constant stream of radio-frequency data and I want to graph it dynamically like an oscilloscope.

I am using C#. Can I use the chart class for this? Are there any readings or videos to help me learn where to start?

Comment: Flagged: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It's fairly simple to draw a graph plot. Do you have specific code that you've gotten stuck on?

Comment: Sorry, I understand now that stackoverflow is a debugging community. Thanks!

Comment: This not really broad: Advice to use the Chart Control is simple and concise.

Comment: There are two options: Remove from the left while adding points to the right or setting the viewport. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250118/scrollbar-moving-to-right-instead-of-left/27251678?s=1|0.5185#27251678) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542701/chart-compression/27077902?s=2|0.3122#27077902) for the latter

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the MS Chart controls that come with Visual Studio.

Here's a good place to start:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx

...and some samples:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: Also, here's a neat little video tutorial for a simple chart in C#:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5NvskjtKU8